# For a Chrome plugin, is an OnClick of a browser tab a Page Action or a  Browser Action?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a plugin in Chrome,without refreshing page i need to fetch email when clicking on browser tabs. i should write code in background.html or browser action(js). but i used in content script.js, it is alerting when i refresh page..

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173891/onclicking-of-browser-tabs-i-want-to-fetch-email-address-without-refreshing-the ? What exactly is the question? Where is the email stored?

Comment: When you "click on browser tabs," that fires the onActivated event. See here:
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onActivated Also, @Fczbkk, that link is dead.